# ajax chat page submitting twice, PHP/Jquery/Mysql

Tags: php, ajax

I've got a really basic chat page I'm working on.  Chat.php basically has a text area, the user types something, hits enter, and submits the form, the ajax form loads chat_window.php into the #refresh div.  After the 1st submit, the second submit for some reason is submitting twice, then the 3rd submit submits 3x..etc etc.  I've also have a interval that reloads a div with chat_window.php every 5 seconds.

chat.php

```
<div class="container">

<?PHP



 echo "<form id='chat_form' method='post' action='processforms/process_chat.php'>";
 echo "<input type='hidden' name='chat_form_submit'>";
 echo "<textarea name='msg' style='width:98%;padding:4px;' id='msg_field'></textarea>";
 echo "</form>";

 echo "<div id='refresh'></div>"; //REFRESH WINDOW (chat_window.php)



?>

</div><!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

chat_window.php

```
<?PHP 
 include ("../includes/mysql.php"); 
 $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY timestamp DESC");
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
  echo $row['msg']."<br>";
 }
?>
```

Javascript

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {// REFRESH INTERVAL
      interval = setTimeout(refreshpage, 5000);
      function refreshpage() {
         $('#refresh').load('includes/chat_window.php?timer='+new Date().getTime(), function () {
          interval = setTimeout(refreshpage, 5000);
         }); 
      }    
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> //CHAT FORM
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        var options = { 
            target:        '',
            dataType:      'html',          
            beforeSubmit:  showRequest_chatform,        
            success:       showResponse_chatform
        }; 
        $(".container").delegate("#chat_form","submit",function () { 
            $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); //submit the form
            return false;
        });
    });
    function showRequest_chatform(formData, jqForm, options) {
        return true; 
    }
    function showResponse_chatform(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form){   
         $('#refresh').load('includes/chat_window.php', function () { 
           $('#msg_field').val("").focus();
         });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: How does it even submit? I don't see anything that would make it submit even once. Your explanation of the problem is too light on details.

Comment: If you look at the JS section you'll see the .delegate("#chat_form","submit") function

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace this line:
`echo "<form id='chat_form' method='post' action='processforms/process_chat.php'>";`

With this line:
`echo "<form id='chat_form' method='post' action='processforms/process_chat.php' onsubmit='return false;'>";`

Tell me how it is working for you?

Comment: OK in this case, can you paste the whole `<form>` code using http://pastebin.com so I can get the whole picture.